# When to use server key and when to use ios key in google map

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, google-maps, api-key

Having some doubt I was trying to call google place `API` in my `iOS` app and for that i need **Google `API` Key** . I go through google developer console and made new iO`enter code here`S key. I run app and its shows the error that **"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key"** . I replace `iOS` key with server key and its working fine. But as per the documentation [(Documentation link)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_apikeys) it define below point:

**Server keys**

Create and use a server key if your application runs on a server. Do not use this key outside of your server code. For example, do not embed it in a web page. To prevent quota theft, restrict your key so that requests are only allowed from your servers' source IP addresses.

**Browser keys**

Create and use a browser key if your application runs on a client, such as a web browser. To prevent your key from being used on unauthorized sites, only allow referrals from domains you administer.

**`iOS` keys**

Create and use an iOS key if your application runs on iOS devices. Google verifies that each request originates from an iOS application that matches one of the bundle identifiers you specify. An app's .plist file contains its bundle identifier. Example: com.example.MyApp

**Android keys**

Create and use an Android key if your application runs on Android devices. To do so, you need to specify the SHA1 fingerprints and package names of the application using that key.

As per the documentation i need to use `iOS` key but ,its not working.  Now my question is **basically as per the protocol which key i have to use?**

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a google supplied SDK then you would use the iOS key.

If you're using the web interface, so `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`, then you would use the browser key.

The server key should only be used if your code making the request is actually running on a server.

Comment: is there a way to restrict a server key to my App's bundle? Because restriction doesn't seem to work. Is restricting server key not required? THe only restriction for server keys supported seems to be IP Address which wont work for mobile apps.

Comment: Because the server key isn't intended to be used by mobile apps @Annjawn - it's supposed to be used for server-to-server requests only

Answer (score 1):

Use only Server key for google map Apis.

**Check Doc :** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

**Steps:**

- Go to the Google Developers Console.
- Create or select a project.
- Click Continue to Enable the API.
- Go to Credentials to get a **Server key** (and set the API Credentials).
- To prevent quota theft, secure your API key following these best practices.
- (Optional) Enable billing. See Usage Limits for more information.

**As per Google Documentation:**

Google Maps APIs are available for Android or iOS apps, Web browsers, and via HTTP Web services. APIs in each platform require a specific type of key. The **Google Maps Geocoding API will only work with a Server key**. APIs of the same platform can use the same key.

To specify a key in your request, include it as the value of a key parameter.

**Example:**
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=62.25227243964484%2C59.12338379770518&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Add your key in example link and you will get result if key is proper.

Happy Coding :)